# Can one use PCA to reduce the dimensionality of One-Hot-Encoded data?

Tags: machine-learning, python, categorical-data, anomaly-detection, dimensionality-reduction

I read a couple times that PCA was used as a method to reduce dimensionality for one-hot-encoded data. However, there were also some comments that using PCA is not a good idea since one-hot-encoded features only contain the values 0 or 1 which is why they will be ignored (I am not sure whether I understood the explaining correctly...).

I work on an unsupervised anomaly detection project with data containing mostly cagetorical features, a bit over 200 features in total. I would like to also use a clustering method so I am not sure whether the results given by PCA are incorrect.

So my question is: Is it possible to use PCA for One-Hot-Encoded data? If not, which other methods can be used ? I try to avoid t-SNE since it depends on its hyperparemeters which makes it a bit difficult in this unsupervised case.

Answer (score 0):

[PCA](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/principal-component-analysis-en) can be used for one-hot-encoded data, but it may not always be the best choice, and you need to be aware of its limitations. When you perform [PCA](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/principal-component-analysis-en) on one-hot-encoded data, it treats the binary variables (0 or 1) as continuous variables and attempts to find linear combinations of these variables that explain the most variance in the data. However, since one-hot-encoded variables are binary and sparse, most of the variance may be concentrated in just a few components, leading to suboptimal results.

Here are some considerations when using [PCA](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/principal-component-analysis-en) with one-hot-encoded data:

1. Loss of Interpretability: [PCA](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/principal-component-analysis-en) will create linear combinations of the binary variables, which can be hard to interpret in the context of the original categorical features. The new components may not correspond to meaningful patterns in the data.
2. Sparse Data Handling: One-hot-encoded data is sparse, and [PCA](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/principal-component-analysis-en) may not be the most efficient method to handle this kind of data. Other dimensionality reduction techniques, like [t-SNE](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/tsne-en) or UMAP, can handle sparse data more effectively and may provide better visualization and clustering results.
3. [Curse of Dimensionality](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/curse-of-dimensionality-en): [PCA](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/principal-component-analysis-en) may not effectively capture the underlying structure of high-dimensional, one-hot-encoded data. The "curse of dimensionality" can cause the PCA components to become noisy and uninformative.

There are specialized techniques like Categorical [PCA](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/principal-component-analysis-en) that are specifically designed for dimensionality reduction on one-hot-encoded data. It takes into account the binary nature of the one-hot-encoded features and can provide better results compared to regular [PCA](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/principal-component-analysis-en).